# Как воспроизводить dash видео

Tags: javascript, видео, dash

Есть множество готовых библиотек для воспроизведения dash видео.
Собственно конвертировать видео dash научился и воспроизводить при помощи сторонних библиотек...

Вопрос в том, что у меня уже есть готовый плеер который воспроизводить mp4 файлы. Необходимо перестроить его на dash файлы.

Кто нибудь может подсказать какие нибудь простые примеры для старта, без использования сторонних библиотех. Уж очень хочется разобраться самостоятельно в данной технологии и в дальнейшем самостоятельно сделать так, чтобы качество видео менялось автоматом относительно пропускной способности пользователя.

Ничего в голову не приходит, даже не представляю как просто запустить dash в теге video.

Comment: «просто запустить dash в теге video» — никак, потому что в браузерах нет встроенной поддержки dash. Берите сторонние библиотеки